# Drag and drop multiple folders to bat file to copy

Tags: batch-file, directory, copy

I created BAT file to copy a folder with music to mobile. This works fine for drag & drop of one folder to it.

```
xcopy /s /i "%~1" "e:\Music\Subfolder\"
```

How can I enhance to multiple folders (drag and drop multiple selected folders)?

Can you help me with some FOR/LOOP cycle?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
@ECHO OFF
:TOP
IF (%1) == () GOTO END
xcopy /s /i "%1" "e:\Music\Subfolder\"
SHIFT
GOTO TOP
:END
ECHO Done!
PAUSE
```

You can access the first dragged file/folder with the `%1` variable. The second one is stored in `%2`, etc. Calling `SHIFT` you "drop" `%1` and move all vars from `%i` to `%i-1`. You keep on looping until `%1` is empty which means that you've shifted through all folders.

Comment: You should change `"%1"` to `"%~1"` as the path will be enclosed with quotes when it contains spaces

Comment: Perfect:) The only issue now is 'Subfolder' name. I would like to replace it with the copied folder's names. To get the same directory structure in Music.

Comment: Yoiu should be able to do that by adjusting the xcopy line (http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html).